# Is it possible to debug Flash with IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: flash, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm trying to debug a Flash project with IntelliJ IDEA. Here is what I get:

> "c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\java.exe"
>   "-Dapplication.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\flash" -Xmx384m
>   -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.awt.headless=true -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=en -Xmx512m -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   11.1.3\plugins\flex\lib\idea-fdb-4.5.0.20967-fix.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/flash/lib/fdb.jar" flex.tools.debugger.cli.DebugCLI Adobe fdb
>   (Flash Player Debugger) [build 23201] Copyright (c) 2004-2007 Adobe,
>   Inc. All rights reserved. Waiting for Player to connect Failed to
>   connect; session timed out. Ensure that:
>   1. you compiled your Flash movie with debugging on, and
>   2. you are running the Debugger version of the Flash Player.

I have compiled my Flash with debugging on. If I go to Project Structure -> Build configuration -> Compiler options,  Generate Debuggable SWF is checked. I am running a debug version of Flash player.

What is wrong?

Comment: Does the Flash application start? In browser (which?) or in standalone Flash Player? If started - right-click the app - do you see 'Show redraw regions' option in popup?

Comment: I start my chrome browser manually. When I right-click swf, no menu opens.

Comment: Looks like you use Flash Remote Debug run configuration, right? If you want to debug the app compiled in IntelliJ IDEA - usual Flash App run configuration would be a better choice. It launches browser or Flash Player automatically.  

Am I right that there's 2 minutes timeout between 'Waiting for Player to connect' and 'Failed to connect' and you open your Chrome tab with swf during this timeout?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it doesn't appear immediately.

Comment: Please try to create a sample Web-targeted Flex app using all defaults of IntelliJ IDEA New Project Wizard and when done - click Debug button. If the app starts, but doesn't connect to the debugger automatically (see Debug tool window) - right-click running swf, select Debugger and then select to connect to localhost.

Comment: There is no way to create flex app, only flash: http://s001.radikal.su/2012/09/27/19d90568.png

Comment: Flash module contains Flash build configuration that can be pure ActionScript or Flex. You'll see it on the next wizard step.

Comment: Alexander, I've just returned to this issue. I can debug application via HTML wrapper or from simple app. But when I run build my app from existing sources, timeout happens and I can't debug. Also debugger menuitem from rightclick is not available. I've verified, I am running debugger version of flash player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with chrome debug version of flash player. SWF file is not identified as debuggable if it comes from local web server. If the same file is opened from file system, it can be debugged. There is no such problem with IE. Hope that would help someone.